# How to HTTP get request with parameters in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, parameters, request

Im working with NODE.js Im using 'request' module :

It works:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.site.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
});
```

When  I try to include parameters it crashs!

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.site.com/index.php?action=y9sadf98yh', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
});

Error: undefined is not a valid uri or options object.
    at request (/node_modules/request/index.js:1217:41)
    at Request._callback (nodeCloseSession/index.js:60:5)
    at Request.self.callback (/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/node_modules/request/index.js:876:14)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/node_modules/request/index.js:827:12)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:883:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

How to use parameters in NODE.js 'request' module?

Comment: Can you post the crash traceback?

Comment: I think you have a bug in your real code but when you tried to simplify it to post here, you avoided it. Whatever you are passing to `request()` in your real code is `undefined`. The example posted works fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try and use [Requestify](http://ranm8.github.io/requestify) as alternative, a small and very simple HTTP client for nodeJS + it supports caching..

To perform your request do the following:

```
var requestify = require('requestify');

requestify.get('http://www.site.com/index.php?action=y9sadf98yh')
  .then(function(response) {
      // Get the response body (JSON parsed or jQuery object for XMLs)
      response.getBody();
  }
);
```

OR:

```
var requestify = require('requestify');

requestify.get('http://www.site.com/index.php', { 
    params: {
      action: 'y9sadf98yh'
    }
})
  .then(function(response) {
      // Get the response body (JSON parsed or jQuery object for XMLs)
      response.getBody();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
request('/www.site.com/', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
});
```

use userAgent to get your parameter vaule